# Request to merge tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I just read a question which was tagged both [dimming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimming) and [dimmer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimmer). That's tag abuse. I propose merging the two. I don't have a preference which one we should keep.

Comment: These both look somewhat poorly used, any idea what it should "mean"?